# Check for paginate object in jinja2

Tags: pagination, jinja2

I have a page which receives a results objects and is supposed to iterate over it. results can be a paginate object, in which case the iteration would be

```
{% for data in results.items %}
```

or it can be a list in which case we would iterate as

```
{% for data in results %}
```

I am now trying to distinguish between the two cases with

```
{% if results.items %}
    {% for data in results.items %}
         // do something with data
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {% for data in results %}
        // do something with data
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

however, in my case it can happen that results.items == 0, which would mean that the if statement is false. Therefore I need to have a way to check whether results.items exists, independent of the value it has. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Could you set a separate variable for that, in your jinja2 code or in the handler code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was easier than I thought...

```
{% if not results or (results.items is defined and not results.items) %}
```